# debian man pages for system calls

Tags: linux, debian, manpage

I installed debian lenny, but I was quite surprised that I can't get man pages for system calls (`man 2 read`, etc.)

How do I install them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
apt-get install manpages-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
```